# Get Contentful to Show More Detailed Errors

Tags: laravel-10, contentful-management

I'm trying to migrate my content on Laravel to Contentful using its Management API for PHP.

Following the tutorials, I was able to get the error to show.

> Validation error

However, the error it shows is very vague. How do I get it to show more detailed errors so I know what fields they occur on?

Here is the function where I put my logic:

```php
    public function posts()
    {
        $records = Post::take(1)->get();
        $count = $records->count();
    
        $environmentProxy = $this->contentful()['environmentProxy'];

        $recordsMigrated = 0;
        foreach($records as $record) {
            $entry = new Entry(ContentfulHelper::$ID_BLOG_POSTS);

            $title = $record->title;

            $entry->setField(ContentfulHelper::$FIELD_TITLE, ContentfulHelper::$DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, $title);
            $entry->setField(ContentfulHelper::$FIELD_SLUG, ContentfulHelper::$DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, AppHelper::instance()->generateSlug($title));
            $entry->setField(ContentfulHelper::$FIELD_CONTENT, ContentfulHelper::$DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, 'Hello');
            $entry->setField(ContentfulHelper::$FIELD_SUMMARY, ContentfulHelper::$DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, $record->summary);

            $entry->setField(ContentfulHelper::$FIELD_META_TITLE, ContentfulHelper::$DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, $record->meta_title);
            $entry->setField(ContentfulHelper::$FIELD_META_DESCRIPTION, ContentfulHelper::$DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, $record->meta_description);

            $entry->setField(ContentfulHelper::$FIELD_FEATURED, ContentfulHelper::$DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, ($record->featured === 1));

            try {
                $environmentProxy->create($entry);
                if ($record->status) {
                  $entry->publish();  
                }
                $recordsMigrated++;
            } catch(Exception $exception) {
                echo $exception->getMessage() . "\n";
                echo "Stopped at record: $record->id\n";
                die();
            }
        }

        return redirect(route('contentful.index'))
            ->with('message', "$recordsMigrated/$count Posts migrated successfully.");
    }
```

**Edit 1**: The "Content" field is a rich text field. Is that the cause? Currently stored content is in `Markdown`.